# Pokemon Black and White for 3DS - Does it exist?

Tags: pokemon-series, nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds

My little cousin is asking for Pokemon Black and White for the 3DS... I can find Black and I can find White but I can't find Black and White as a single game. Did I misunderstand?

Is there a Pokemon Black and White game for the 3DS?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No.

He either wants Pokémon White OR Pokémon Black, or Pokémon White AND Pokémon Black.

Comment: Also, Black, White, Black 2, and White 2 are all for the DS, not the 3DS.

Comment: It should be noted that DS games work just fine in a 3DS.

Answer (score 0):

There is no 3D Pokemon Games yet except for  X and Y.

But they work fine IN a 3DS, they're just not 3D because they weren't originally designed for a 3D machine.
Hope this helps.